# 2D array reading issue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-for-education

I want to create a sort of "stack" and every time I delete an item, the sheet removes the blank cells. I can't use a filter function for this, obviously.

I am having trouble reading the array that is created for this purpose.

My very pseudo-code : I create an empty array, get all the values (including the empty ones), populate my array with all the values except the empty ones, and finally clear the stack and set the values with my array.

Here is my code :

```js
function updateStack() {
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("main");
  
 var zone = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 10);
  
  //seems that .getValues() returns a 2d array

 var values = zone.getValues();
 var j = 0;
  
 var data = new Array();
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

    //the problem seems to be here : I can't access the 2d array. After reading the debugging console about 1000 thousand times
    // I discovered the 2 pairs of []  
    
    //I've found multiple ways to detect empty cells. Not sure if this is the right one. I've tried the .length = 0 trick, but something
    // was wrong, maybe because of the "2dimensionality"

    
    if (values[i] != "") {
      
      data[j] = values[i];
      j = j++;
      
    } else {
      
      // do nothing if the cell contains nothing
     
    }
   
  //not sure if I have to use return ! Don't know where to put it exactly too...
  return data; 
  zone.clear();
    //length of range must be the same as the array's length
    
  zone = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, data.length);
  zone.setValues(data);
  }
}
```

There are many comments in my code, I hope you will understand. 
A link to my test sheet : http://bit.ly/1JiWutn

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I understood it right up until you mention the sheet removing blank cells... You might want to include some intermediate step/info.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. I've edited it, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have a section of code like this:

```
if (values[i] != "") {

  data[j] = values[i];
  j = j++;

} else {
```

You are testing for an empty string:

```
values[i] != ""
```

But `values[i]` is an inner array.  Your code is getting only one row, and 10 columns.

```
var zone = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 10);
```

So, the array looks like this:

```
[ [cell one,cell two,cell three,etc,cell ten ] ]
```

`values[i]` returns an inner array, not a value.

To get the cell value use:

```
if (values[0][i] != "") {
```

You need two indexes, the first index will always be zero.  There is only one inner array with all the cell values in it.

Next, use `push` to add a value to the `data` array:

```
data.push(values[0][i]);
```

Another issue is where you have the `return` statement.  A `return` statement kills the current function.  Anything after the `return` statement inside of that function will not run.  So, you can't have a return statement where you have it, and get the code to write values to the spreadsheet.  You can do both.  You can both write values to the sheet, and return something, but put the return at the end.  The return, returns something to whatever function called this function.

To set values, the values MUST be in a two dimensional array.  Your `data` array is not a 2D array.  You must add the `data` array to yet another array.

```
var my2Darray = [];
my2Darray.push(data);

zone = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, data.length);
zone.setValues(my2Darray);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've modified the code, but it doesn't work. I am not sure of the double index, because the debugging console gave me

[["987sdf987", 987, 987, " ", 4654, 7, 987987, " ", "", ""]]

and that makes me think : this is an array with ONE array inside. So, if I want to access an item in it, it will be data[0][i].

Comment: Oh, yes, my mistake.  Sorry about that.  I updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I am very proud I've pointed this, it's the first script of my life ! 
Still having trouble with the 'return' thing : where to put it ? If I omit it, says impossible to convert Array in object, and if I put it, it clears my stack but doesn't write my values.

Comment: See updated answer.  Put return statement at end, if needed.  Must use a 2D array to set values.

Comment: i think your `my2Darray` edit has confused matters a little. Your first answer where you add a `values` row to the `data` array is sufficient. wrapping data in array will not give the expected result. it will be transposed horizontally. In your code example of 2D checking there will need to be an intermediary `dataRow` array which gets added to `data` at the conclusion of the inner loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "transposed horizontally"?

Comment: the `my2Darray` did the trick. @Jonathon @ Sandy Thank you very much for answering my first question on stack... overflow !

Comment: my brain was transposing the problem - i assumed the stack was a selection of rows - re-reading it is in fact columnar. my bad.

Comment: No, problem.  You get a free pass.  lol.  As long I can redeem one myself later.

Comment: no idea of the source of this data, but aggregating and presumably appending data in a columnar fashion is just about the opposite of the way I expected anyone else to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only testing for blank cells across a whole row then the test you have is almost usable. If you concatenate all the values in that array then the resultant can be compared to `""`.

```
// join all the values with nothing between them
// compare the result to empty string
if(values[i].join("") !== "") { 

  // if at least one cell contained something
  data.push(values[i]); // Stackius Popularious


}
```

Comment: i've misread the question - i assumed the range was a 2D one consisting of rows and columns - in fact it is a single row with just columns